# WCSession sendMessage errorHandler called multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, sendmessage, watchconnectivity

I'm using `WatchKit 2.0`, and am noticing a very strange behavior. If I'm using my watch app for over 5 minutes, I start getting timeout errors from the `WCSession` `sendMessage` call, which has previously been called and completed successfully. I print out the error as:

```
Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7012 "Message reply took too long." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Message reply took too long., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Reply timeout occured.}
```

I can still make other calls in different `Interface Controllers`, but I keep getting `errorHandlers` called in `Interface Controllers` which have been closed (used back button on top).

Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior? I do not combine hierarchical and page-based interface styles in the code, and everything behaves for the first 5 minutes while using the application.

### UPDATE

Here is the code:

```
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        // Set the session to default session singleton
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()

        // Fire the message to iPhone app
        session.sendMessage(["action": "getProfile", "memberId": citizen!.memberId], replyHandler: { (response) -> Void in


            if response["messageData"] != nil {
                // There is data in the reply
                let jsonObject = JSON(response["messageData"]!)

                ...

                // Display the profile details
                self.displayProfileDetails()



            } else if response["error"] != nil {
                // Get the error message and display it
                self.showAlert(nil, message: WatchUtils.getErrorString(response["error"]), action: .GET_PROFILE)
            }
            }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                print("error: \(error)")
                // Show alert
                self.showAlert(nil, message: NSLocalizedString("watch_connectivity_error", comment: "Watch can't connect to phone"), action: .GET_PROFILE)
        })
    }
```

The `replyHandler` gets called initially, but for some reason after 5 minutes the `errorHandler` is called, and keeps getting called every couple of seconds.

Comment: Please provide your `sendMessage` and `didReceiveMessage` code.

Comment: Looks like an apple representative saying this is a bug they are tracking: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/126489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem a few months ago. The solution I came up with was using a variable to store the id I gave to the last request made, for instance

self.lastCallId = "watch_load_clients"

And if the matching id isn't received (I also send the id back) then I ignore the request.

I think it's just a Bluetooth issue.

Edit: Also, are you making requests and not receiving a response? That is the case when your problem should happen.

Comment: I have thought of going that route before, but just wasn't sure if there was an underlying problem. I am getting a response back, but if I keep my application open, seems like 5 minutes is the magic number when the `errorHandler` gets called

Comment: Yea I think it's either an API issue or a Bluetooth connectivity issue. If my solution works for you then go for it. Works for me fine.

Comment: @TonyFriz can you show me how to ignore the request?

It happens when I sendMessage frequently also. Then there will be a running animation on WatchApp and then it shows the error.

Comment: I checked my code and I actually don't use the method I posted above although that should still work. As I said, give identifiers to all actions/messages your watch communication requires to function correctly and store in a property/iVar the most recent communication identifier. And then when session:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler: is called only respond to the communication identifier that is being stored in your iVar.